# Deserialize json array and extract value using rest assured

Tags: json, gson, rest-assured

I am a java, json, rest assured newbie and trying to work and learn how to test a rest api. I have an array returned as a rest assured response:

```
 Response response = given(getProjectInfoRequest).get();
 response.asString(); 

{
    "options": [
        {
            "text": "111",
            "label": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "text": "222",
            "label": "DEF"
        },
        {
            "text": "333",
            "label": "GHI"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to extract the value of text say for label value as "DEF", how I can do that?

Please note I have done below so far after reading through so many posts:

```
1. Options[] options = given(getProjectInfoRequest).when().get().as(Options[].class);
this was giving me exception :
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

then I tried below:
2. Options options = gson.fromJson(response.asString(), Options.getClass());
this at least resolved the above issue.
    public class Options {
    public String getLabel() {
        return label
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }
    public String label;
    public String value;
}
```

From this point I am not sure how I can iterate through the array of text and values to extract what I need, please can you guys provide your inputs?

Please pardon my ignorance for asking such a basic question.
Please also suggest me a good source/way to learn this too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[U can use Gson -](https://github.com/google/gson) This is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse(response.asString());

for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : o.entrySet()) {
    JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement elementJSON : array) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. For some reason I am not able to convert the RestAssured response to JsonObject. I tried below codes:
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject object = jsonParser.parse(response.asString()).getAsJsonObject();

then I tried 
 JsonElement element = new JsonPrimitive(response.asString());
 JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();

both of them threw exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"value":"....

any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks a ton man. I was so stuck yesterday night/morning. :) I did have to modify a little bit but after that it worked. Here is the portion I needed to modify:
 for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
            JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
            for (JsonObject objJSON : array) { ...some code here}

Comment: I wanted to vote up your answer but I don't have required reputation yet. :) Thanks once again, please can you suggest me a good tutorial for gson- json-java? I want to learn more about this.

Comment: Thanks man, as soon I have the required reputation I will. :)

Comment: Hey I still unable to do it. Every time I try to do it I get message "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". This is my new account for stackoverflow that is why probably. I will do it as soon I have the required reputation.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that option earlier. I just marked it. Thanks learnt stackoverflow a little bit more. :)